# appDelegate managedObjectContext spread across codebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When using core data. I find myself writing the code

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

// Code here

[context save:nil];
```

everywhere in the codebase. Is this normal or is this an antipattern? I usually only use one context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Core Data on several places in the app, you could use a Singleton class which handles the basic Core Data logic and holds the `persistentStoreCoordinator`, `managedObjectModel` and of course the wanted `managedObjectContext`.

```
@interface DataManager : NSObject

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

+ (DataManager *)sharedManager;
- (void)saveContext;

@end
```

Then you can use the context anywhere like this

```
#import "DataManager.h"

...

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[DataManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext];

// Do some Core Data action
```

I wouldn't recommend to add a property on AppDelegate since the AppDelegate is there for handling Application events, not storing data. It's just cleaner. By the way.. I always try to follow the "Single Responsibility Principle" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 1):

AppDelegate.h

```
+(AppDelegate *)sharedManager;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
+(AppDelegate *)sharedManager
{
    static AppDelegate *sharedMyManager = nil;
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedMyManager == nil)
        {
            sharedMyManager = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        }
    }
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

So using `[[AppDelegate sharedManager] managedObjectContext]` this line, you can easily access shared MOC in app

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the singleton pattern, you could pass references to your context throughout the app. Every one of your view controllers in your app would need to keep a reference to the context so that it can pass it on to the next view controller. You could pass the context it in an initializer or use a property.

```
// Example class interface. All of your view controllers would look like this.
// You could put this stuff in a protocol as well.
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *context

    // or

    - (instancetype)initWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
}
```

When your application begins, you will need to load your `NSManagedObjectContext` and pass it to any view controller that comes on screen, either through initializing them or in `prepareForSegue`. You can initialize this in your `AppDelegate` if you launch your app through code, or you could load it in the `viewDidLoad` of your initial view controller. Here is an example of this in the `AppDelegate`.

```
- application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = // get your context

    // initialize your view controller or get it from the storyboard or put this code where ever your app starts
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithContext:context];

    // or pass the context as a property
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.context = context;

    window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```